# Cache popular files on a local SSD from a large repository of files on a local/LAN spin drive

Tags: windows, hard-disk, caching, ssd

A friend of mine has a relatively small SSD as his primary drive and he likes to store, in addition to the OS and applications, all his CAD data and other documents. Currently, he saving up for a larger SSD and is constantly fighting for "breathing room" on this SSD because he would prefer not to migrate his data, which takes several GB, to his larger spin drive.

At work, I found out about DFS, which has as one of its features, the ability to give the end-user the impression that s/he is accessing a single file store but in fact, only the files she recently accessed are local. The rest are seamlessly stored only on remote server. In other words, all files are stored remotely on a file server while the recently-accessed ones are also cached on a local file server. Please correct me if that is inaccurate.

Regardless, is there something free or cheap that does something similar between two drives on a local workstation or between a local drive and a NAS? All files are stored on the user's large spin drive while only recently-accessed ones are cached on the user's SSD--all maintained seamlessly to the user?

It should be for Windows, and the price limit is pretty low. Keep in mind that this is a stopgap while he saves for a bigger SSD.

Apologies for initially posting the same question to [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1324978/is-there-something-like-dfs-for-a-single-computer-with-a-fast-and-slow-drive).

Comment: Windows, and the price limit is pretty low. Keep in mind that this is a stopgap while he saves for a bigger SSD.. I'll ask him, but what are the options that you know of?

Comment: Me? None. But those details are needed to make good recommendations.